# objective-c - Swift classes are not visible in Objective-C .h file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, swift

I'm trying to use Swift class in my Objective-C file.
I included `"moduleName-Swift.h"` file in my `SuperViewController.m` file, but when I try to declare a public method in `SuperViewController.h` with `Swift-class` as method parameter, I obviously get an error: `"Expected a type"`

How can I use `swift-class` in a header file if I can only include `projectModule-Swift.h` in `.m` files??

Comment: I think you can set @objc in front of the swift class name: (at)objc class myModel : NSObject{..}

Comment: yes, I did that, the class is perfectly visible in .m file, but not in .h file.

Comment: In your h-file use @class myModel under ur imports?

Comment: yes, that solved it :) If you put it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Make sure to put @objc before the **swift** class name.

```
@objc myclassname { ... }
```

Also add

```
@class myclassname;
```

in your **obj-c header file** where you want to access the swift class

Comment: with@ class I get 'Receiver 'XY' for class message is a forward declaration

Comment: Hello @Eyeball , do you know how to access Bool & Int Properties as well ?!

Comment: Adding @objc is now deprecated. This was correct before, but now the correct answer is the one from @andrewz, you need to `#import <MyProjectName-Swift.h>` in your objc file and then it will have access to those Swift classes.

Answer (score 9):

Remember to import the project generated swift header file in your source file, for example `#import <MyProjectName-Swift.h>`

Comment: That's it. That's the one that fixes it. Because adding @objc before the swift class definition is deprecated now. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Adding @class MyClassName in obj-c .h file created the "Receiver 'MyClassName' for class message is a forward declaration" error, so I deleted that and ONLY added the "@objc" before the swift class name, BUT I also had to make sure that the swift class is a subclass of NSObject.

```
@objc class MySwiftClass:NSObject { ... }
```

WITHOUT @class MyClassName in obj-c .h file!

Answer (score 2):

I had to use:

`@obj public class MySwiftClass: NSObject { ... }`

Answer (score 2):

I created a class with no subclass, adding @objc and @objcmembers did not work.
After I change do `:NSObject` the entire class turn visible to objective-C